# How to concatenate array of tuples that contains arrays in Julia

Tags: arrays, tuples, julia

Let's say I have an array `x` like this:

```
x = [(i*ones(4,4,3),rand(11),rand(1:10)) for i=1:5];
```

Now, I want to concatenate them from the last dimension. I mean, at the end of operation, I want to have 3 arrays. The size of the first array need to be `(4,4,3,5)` [concatenation of 5 ones(4,4,3) array)], the second one (11,5) and the last one is (1,5) size.How can I do it in julia ?

**EDIT**
Of course, I can do  it  like below,  but I want to hear if there is a clever way(in terms of memory consumption and speed performance):

```
julia> i=[ t[1] for t in x];

julia> q=[ t[2] for t in x];

julia> l=[ t[3] for t in x];

julia> (cat(4,i...),cat(2,q...),reshape(l,1,length(l))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way could be:

```
ntuple(s->reshape(
  [x[i][s][j] for j in eachindex(first(x)[s]), i=1:length(x)],
  size(first(x)[s])..., length(x)
), length(first(x)))
```

which saves a bit of time & memory (depending on the sizes/shapes in `x`) but the longer solution in the question should be OK. BTW, because this version works for different shapes and lengths of `x` (unlike the version in the question) it looks a bit more cryptic.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion,I'll wait a bit before accepting your answer to see other alternatives